# Validation of the email field

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I am using validate.js to validate the contact form.

It works fine but issue is email validation seems broken at some intervals

For eg: `if email is abc@xyz`        , then it considers email valid 
        `but if email is abc@xyz.`   , then it considers email invalid

Can't it be like, i.e only consider email valid when abc@xyz.lkj

Following is the regular expression being used

```
 /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test( value )
```

I have no idea about regular expressions.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Also if you're using html 5, you might use `<input type="email">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:
`/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i`